# React: useLayoutEffect + useState running sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-state, event-listener

I have been reading about this two hooks and try to find a workaround for my case now here but I cannot make it to work.

Basically, what I want to do is to render a certain amount of images if I am in desktop but less if I am in mobile (in this last case, I need a button to show the rest of the images)

So what did I do?
started simply:

```
                    {images.slice(0, open ? images.length : 6).map(item => {
                        return (
                            <div}>
                                <Image
                                    src={whatever}
                                    alt={whatever}
                                />
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
```

In this way, I can show every image or only 6 if mobile.
Even the button, quite simple

```
                <Button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setOpen(!open);
                    }}
                >
                    {open ? (
                        <text>                         
                           close
                        </text>
                    ) : (
                        <text>                         
                           open
                        </text>
                    )}
```

now, what would be my initial state? well, that should depend on whats the width of the screen, right?
okey, so this is how I solved it:

```
    const [size, setSize] = useState([0]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        function updateSize() {
            setSize([window.innerWidth]);
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
        updateSize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
    }, []);
```

perfect, now I have 'size' who tells me the width of the screen at any moment the user changes the layout.
So now its when I am getting stuck:
There is no way to initialize 'open' to true or false depending on if size is > || < than a certain width.
If I do like this:

```
    const isMobile = size < breakpoints.tablet;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(isMobile);
```

here for example, if I load the page on desktop, 'isMobile' is false, but 'open' is still true.

or

```
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(size < breakpoints.tablet);
```

but still, the value of 'isMobile' and 'open' are not sync. I guess because useLayoutEffect runs synchronously while useState async?
In any case, how can I achieve having the 'open' variable having the correct initial state of 'isMobile'?

Comment: 1) your `size` state is an array, so the comparison in `isMobile` won't be doing what you expect. Easiest is just to remove those arrays as there's only a single number you care about. 2) there's no need to use state for `open` you can just do `const open = size < breakpoints.tablet` and keep things nice and simple

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, for 1) I meant replacing `const [size, setSize] = useState([0])` with `const [size, setSize] = useState(0)` and similarly for the `setSize` call a few lines down

Comment: Thank you for catching it. I was not aware that was the array what stopped me doing was I wanted.
Regarding the open state, I think I still need it to 'show more' or 'show less' when the viewport is on mobile. @RobinZigmond

Comment: Okey so the way that I could do it is: const [open, setOpen] = useState(size > breakpoints.tablet);
and then add a useEffect. This works but I guess is too gross:

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpen(size > breakpoints.tablet);
    }, [size]);

Comment: I still don't see why you need to do any of that. Because `size` is a state variable the component will be rerendered whenever that changes, which means your function will rerun, so any definition of `open` based on `size` will recalculate to the updated value and cause the correct thing to be rendered.